# jquerymobile - navigation in multi-page template

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a multi-page template set up.  The first page has a set of links to the inner pages - however all but one link to the same #template page which loads data dynamically.  The other link is to a form which I have built within the page.

Problem I'm having is when you navigate to one of the links, continue through the pages and then use the back button to get back to the first page, if you then click the link to the form it doesn't navigate to the #page, it goes to the last page you were on in the other links.

Hope that makes sense - maybe a diagram will make it clearer

home > product list > product detail

product detail > product list > home (back button)

home > contact form

This last step shows the product detail page again, instead of the contact form.  It's as if it's not clearing the page out:

My code (truncated for clarity):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.support.cors = true;
    });

    $(document).delegate("#pageDetail", "pagecreate", function () {
        $(this).css('background', '#ECF2FE');//`this` refers to `#pageDetail`
    });

    $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {           
        // We only want to handle changePage() calls where the caller is
        // asking us to load a page by URL.         

        if (typeof data.toPage === "string") {
            $.mobile.pageData = (data && data.options && data.options.pageData) ? data.options.pageData : null;
            // We are being asked to load a page by URL, but we only
            // want to handle URLs that request the data for a specific
            // category.

            var page;
            var type;
            var cat;
            if ($.mobile.pageData && $.mobile.pageData.type) {
                type = $.mobile.pageData.type;
            }

            if ($.mobile.pageData && $.mobile.pageData.cat) {
                cat = $.mobile.pageData.cat;
            }

            if ($.mobile.pageData && $.mobile.pageData.page) {
                page = $.mobile.pageData.page;
            }

            var url = $.url(data.toPage);   //  page url
            var hash = url.fsegment(1).replace(/&.*/, "");  //  nav hash for page holder            

            switch (hash) {
                case "pageList":
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/myapp/" + type + ".aspx?type=" + type,
                        datatype: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('.submenu').html(data);
                            $('.title').html(type);
                            $('.submenu').trigger('create');
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case "pageDetail":
                    $('.detail').load('http://localhost/myapp/' + type + '.aspx?page=' + page + '&type=' + type + ' #contentdiv', function () {
                        $(this).trigger('create');
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
```

HTML bits

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#pageList?type=products" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/Icon-Courses.png" alt="courses" /></a><br />
        <a href="#contactForm" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/Icon-Contact.png" alt="contact" /></a>              
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="pageList" data-add-back-btn="true" style="background-color:#F0F0F0 !important;">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">          
        <h1 class="title">Products</h1>      
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="submenu">   
        <!-- content gets put in here -->
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="pageDetail" data-add-back-btn="true" style="background-color:#F0F0F0 !important;">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">          
        <h1 class="title">Products</h1>      
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="submenu">   
        <!-- content gets put in here -->
    </div>

</div>


<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="contactForm" data-add-back-btn="true" class="detailpage" style="background-color:#F0F0F0 !important;">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">          
        <h1 class="title">Contact Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="detail">
        <div id="contentdiv" style="margin:10px auto;width:90%;">
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" style="width:90%;" data-mini="true" />
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" style="width:90%;" data-mini="true" />
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" style="width:90%;" data-mini="true" />
            <label for="comments">Enquiry / Comments</label>
            <textarea id="comments" rows="80" style="width:90%;" data-mini="true"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Enquiry Now" />                
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the jqm.page.params.js for handling the querystring parameters.

Is there anything obvious there?  The links to the #pageDetail page are returned within the content shown on #pageList.

Don't understand why I can't seem to clear the cache and it doesn't navigate correctly to the contact form if you've been anywhere else first.  if you go straight there it works fine.

Anyone shed any light?  BTW this needs to work using PhoneGap as a standalone

Thanks

Comment: I should add I've dropped in alerts in the javascript to catch the hash and it's definitely catching the right thing, just not going to the right place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually feel a bit dim about this, but it's because I had the same class names on multiple divs and it was using those to import data - so when it was loading data remotely it was putting it in more than one place, overwriting the form at the same time...